# How to get params value in action on link click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My view code is

```
<%= form_for(@payment,:url => verify_payment_payment_index_path) do |f| %>
  <%= f.radio_button("amount", "10") %>
  <%= label :amount, '10 Rs',:style => "display:inline" %> <br>
  <%= f.radio_button("amount", "20") %>
  <%= label :amount, '20 rs',:style => "display:inline" %><br>
  <%= f.radio_button("amount", "50") %>
  <%= label :amount, '50 rs',:style => "display:inline" %><br>
  <%= f.radio_button :amount, '100' %> 
  <%= label :amount, '100 rs',:style => "display:inline" %><br>    
  <%= link_to "Make Payment", verify_payment_payment_index_url, 
              :class => "btn",
              :data => { :toggle => "modal",
                         "target" => "#myBox" },
              "for"=>"Make Payment" %>

<% end %>
```

And I want to access all values in params in controller action after click on link "Make Payment". So how can I achieve it in rails 3?. Please note that I have to open lightbox on click of link and then submit form

Answer (score 1):

you need to submit the form!
so try the following:

```
<%= form_for(@payment,:url => verify_payment_payment_index_path) do |f| %>
   <%= f.radio_button("amount", "10") %>
   <%= label :amount, '10 Rs',:style => "display:inline" %> <br>
   <%= f.radio_button("amount", "20") %>
   <%= label :amount, '20 rs',:style => "display:inline" %><br>
   <%= f.radio_button("amount", "50") %>
   <%= label :amount, '50 rs',:style => "display:inline" %><br>
   <%= f.radio_button :amount, '100' %> 
   <%= label :amount, '100 rs',:style => "display:inline" %><br>

   <%= f.submit "Make Payment", :class=>"btn",:data => {:toggle => "modal","target"=>"#myBox"},"for"=>"Make Payment" %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: You don't need to specify a submit url in `f.submit`. Form will be submitted to the url in the form action attribute.

Comment: But I want to display twitter-lightbox on click link and save the data when click on it

Comment: In this case you need to write javascript that will show the lightbox and then submit the form. Please edit your question to provide correct information.